# Form not posting data

Tags: php, jquery, html

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NqaZ2/4/

I have two forms on a page, One posts fine but the other does not post anything:

```
<form id="comment-oa" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="coa" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="value" value="" />
</form>
```

Its being submitted through jquery:

```
$('a[data-role="fc-delete"]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'),
        spl = id.split("-");

    $('#comment-oa input[name="action"]').attr('value', "delete");
    $('#comment-oa input[name="value"]').attr('value', spl[0]);
    $('#comment-oa').submit();

});
```

and I'm simply just doing `print_r($_POST)` at the moment, but it just comes up with `Array ( )`.

I've checked whether jQuery puts values in and it does (firefox inspector pic):

[image]

EDIT:

The other form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="reply-id" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post comment" />
    <input type="button" value="cancel" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

Comment: You purposely removed the POST's url in the `action` attribute ? I see no URL here.

Comment: @Pranav C Balan - shouldn't that just post to the current url

Comment: Its all done on the same page, So no url needed.

Comment: Are the two forms same?

Comment: Do both forms have the same id?

Comment: `id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id')` what is returning to you??

Comment: What's the id of the other form? It's not the same is it?

Comment: Added the other form to the post.

Comment: Never use `.attr()` to set the value! Use `.val()` instead.

Comment: @jai its in the pic on the post, That works fine.

Comment: The page reloads when you click the link, you said post is empty right? It submits but just not the data?

Comment: @TristanCunningham `$('a[data-role="fc-delete"]')` i don't see any anchor like this in your code. Would you post your relative markup code??

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Yeah, it submits, just no data.

Comment: Add a submit button, to the form, I'm grasping for straws but that stands out in my mind!

Comment: Your not submitting the right form there is a static value in it, 'coa'

Comment: Where is => fc-delete ?How will you submit data

Comment: Which form is working properly ? 1st or 2nd in code u gave?

Comment: @TristanCunningham ,please post jsFiddle

Comment: I've added Js fiddle to top of the post - updated

Comment: its a link without preventDefault()

Comment: @everyone including me, lol .. its the simple ones that get you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update:

```
$('a[data-role="fc-delete"]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'),
        spl = id.split("-");

    $('#comment-oa input[name="action"]').attr('value', "delete");
    $('#comment-oa input[name="value"]').attr('value', spl[0]);
    $('#comment-oa').submit();

});
```

to

```
$('a[data-role="fc-delete"]').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'),
        spl = id.split("-");

    $('#comment-oa input[name="action"]').attr('value', "delete");
    $('#comment-oa input[name="value"]').attr('value', spl[0]);
    $('#comment-oa').submit();

});
```

Your using a link without preventing it form well - linking.

Comment: he using `jQuery` to fire submit event